Async event handler processing causing unexpected execution flow
I was working on a legacy application that had a bug in it and eventually tracked it down to some async event handlers executing in the form of event1 programmatically triggering event2. The original code issue looked like this and I've simplified the code for the sake of reading it:
Public Async Sub MyBaseLoad() Handles MyBase.Load
    //some async operations happen up here
    Method1()
    SomeMethodHere()
End Sub

Public Sub Method1()
    ' Set DataSource which triggers the SelectedIndexChanged event
    myListBox.DataSource = myDataTable
End Sub

Public Async Sub Method2() Handles myListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Perform Basic Logic
    Await LoadMyData()
    Method3()
End Sub

Public Async Function LoadMyData() As Task(Of Boolean)
    ' Perform basic logic
    Await CustomMethod()
End Function

Public Sub Method3()
    ' Code here not important
End Sub

What was happening was that when the MyBaseLoad was executing through Method1, its processing was triggering the SelectedIndexChanged event, which eventually got an Await LoadMyData() and when it got to the last Await in the call stack - CustomMethod, it returned execution all the way back up to MyBaseLoad and SomeMethodHere was being executed before Method1 had finished. So, SomeMethodHere was called before Method3 and created an issue where a bool was the wrong value. I thought that by maybe making the flow async and Awaiting, It would work how I wanted so I tried something like this:
Public Async Sub MyBaseLoad() Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Execute Method1 asynchronously
    Await Method1()
    SomeMethodHere()
End Sub

Public Async Function Method1() As Task
    ' Await MyListBoxPropAssigment asynchronously
    Await MyListBoxPropAssigment()
End Function

Private Async Function MyListBoxPropAssigment() As Task
    ' Set DataSource which triggers the SelectedIndexChanged event
    myListBox.DataSource = myDataTable
    Await Task.Delay(0)
End Function

Public Async Sub Method2() Handles myListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' Perform Basic Logic
    Await LoadMyData()
    Method3()
End Sub

Public Async Function LoadMyData() As Task(Of Boolean)
    ' Perform basic logic
    Await CustomMethod()
End Function

Public Sub Method3()
    ' Code here not important
End Sub

this didn't change anything and SomeMethodHere() was still being executed before Method3(). Now, I was able to solve this by using a TaskCompletionSource(Of Boolean) and changing MyListBoxPropAssigment() to await the TaskCompletionSource's Task where the result is set to true at the end of Method2(), but I don't love the solution and am not sure if that is a "good" one either. Is anyone able to explain how the async event handlers are processing and what a good solution would be? I think the MyBase.Load event triggering the SelectedIndexChanged is not ideal and a bool to prevent its entire execution on Load is one solution, but would like to understand the core issue.

I think that you have been beaten by the fact that asynchronous event handlers cannot be awaited. The event-based system of the existing UI frameworks has not been built with asynchrony in mind, and that's why Microsoft invented the concept of async void, to cope with the limitation in the existing infrastructure. In your case you have two async void event handlers that are running concurrently, and so the order of their execution is not predictable.
I don't think that there is any pretty solution to be found for this problem. The solution that you've chosen, adding a TaskCompletionSource<bool> field in the form, sounds quite brittle to me. It makes an already complex problem even more complex. I would prefer to use the classic workaround of using a bool field that suspends temporarily the execution of event handlers. In my projects I usually do this:
At the top of the form:
private bool _eventsDisabled;

Then I add a utility method that invokes a synchronous (Action) or asynchronous (Func<Task>) action, disabling the event handlers until the action completes:
private async Task WithEventsDisabled(Func<Task> action)
{
    bool oldEventsDisabled = _eventsDisabled;
    _eventsDisabled = true;
    try
    {
        await action();
    }
    finally
    {
        _eventsDisabled = oldEventsDisabled;
    }
}

At the top of all event handlers:
private async void myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_eventsDisabled) return;
    //...
}

Using the WithEventsDisabled utility method, to wrap calls that are raising events and are causing a mess:
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await WithEventsDisabled(async () =>
    {
        //some async operations happen up here
        Method1();
    });
    SomeMethodHere();
}

I think that this way is easier to understand what's going on, during both the initial development and maintenance.

Thanks for the response! I definitely agree that the TaskCompletionSource wasnt a great option and even mentioned a bool would be a solution. I like the approach you are showing and think I will go a similar route. Thanks again!

Addressing just MyBase.Load...  I was able to stop the SelectedIndexChanged event by changing the SelectionMode.
Test code.
Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim tsk As Task
    tsk = Task.Run(Sub()
                       Dim nums As New List(Of Integer)
                       nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000).ToList
                       Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                          Dim selMode As Windows.Forms.SelectionMode = ListBox1.SelectionMode 'designer mode
                                          'run this with the code as is and then 
                                          '  comment the next line.
                                          ListBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                                          ListBox1.DataSource = nums
                                          ListBox1.SelectionMode = selMode
                                      End Sub)
                   End Sub)
    Await tsk
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim lb As ListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    Debug.WriteLine(lb.SelectedIndex)
End Sub 'set break here

